# Image with unknown origin causing mixed content on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http, url, https, mixed-content

there's this strange image loaded via http from blogspot and I don't know why.
It's causing mixed content on the website.

[Piemme2nastri](https://www.piemme2nastri.it/)

You can see it in the console, it's an image with a Bus in it, lol. I've never seen that image and I can't find the source in the code. Searched everywhere, it says it's loaded from a jquery file but there's nothing about that url in it.

Hope you could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be caused by one of your plugin. You can try deactivating them one by one to detect which one if causing this issue.

I found this post if it helps you [SSL issue with Smart Slider 3](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ssl-issue-14/)

If you really need to use this plugin, there are some WP plugins available to fix mixed content.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Just added the S on the "http" part of the url in the file. Solved.
Thank  you Julia :)

Comment: You're welcome and I hope everything's well for you in Italy

Comment: We still have a lot to learn about civic sense but it's getting better day by day. 
Thanks for asking.